# How to search for a face in an image?

Tags: android, google-mlkit, android-developer-api

I took a project which requires to search for a face(extracted from an image using google's ML kit).
What I'm stuck at is, an algorithm to find that face in a group of photos(that may contain several faces). PLease help.
I searched the internet but got no method that could search a particular face in images with multiple faces.
Thanks!

I searched the internet but got no method that could search a particular face in images with multiple faces.

Comment: Can you find all the faces in an image?

Comment: Detect faces with ML Kit on Android https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below listed some libraries

**Google ML kit** Free

**TensorFlow** Free and paid

**OpenCV** Free ( Open source )